# Xamarin android format string onkey pressed

Tags: android, xamarin, onkeyup

I have this EditText in which I want the user to type a credit card number, so I want to format the string while the user is typing it, I specifically want the string to have a space every 4 numbers, like this:

xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx

I found that I could use TextWatcher and onKeyUp but I couldn't understand how use it in a EditText, if some one could explain me I would really appreciate it, thanks.

Comment: Do you mean use it with an `EditText`? The user isn't allowed to type in a `TextView`, so none of that is going to work.

Comment: Yes, sorry I meant EditText

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a class that implements the `ITextWatcher` interface. Then add an instance of that class as a text changed listener...

```
public class CreditCardFormatter : Java.Lang.Object, ITextWatcher
{
    private EditText _editText;
    public CreditCardFormatter(EditText editText)
    {
     _editText = editText;
    }

    public void AfterTextChanged(IEditable s)
    {
    }

    public void BeforeTextChanged(ICharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
    {
    }

    public void OnTextChanged(ICharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
    {
    }
}
```

In your activity.. (or `OnCreateView` in a fragment)

```
public override void OnCreate()
{
    // other code..
    myEditText.AddTextChangedListener(new CreditCardFormatter(myEditText));
}
```

Then use the override methods to reformat the text to show what you need.

Comment: Where do I need to place the code? inside of OnTextChanged? why do I need to override the oncreate?

Comment: You pass the instance of the class in the OnCreate method of the activity(or OnCreateView method of a fragment).

Comment: Thanks for this! only one thing, when I place the space between characters, the focus change from the end of the string to before the 4 characters, instead of:
XXXX |

it goes to:
|XXXX

Comment: You have access to the edit text, so you can change where the cursor is

Comment: Thanks! It works now! I added _editText.SetSelection(_editText.Length()); and now is working, thanks a lot :)